# Can jquery-2.2.4 JQMIGRATE warnings for AngularJS v1.4.5 be ignored and AngularJS be upgraded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have jquery 2.2.4 and AngularJS v1.4.5 set up on my website. I set up the jquery-migratjquery-migrate-1.4.1 and get the warning:

```
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.attr('selected') might use property instead of attribute
```

The only attr is being called by the angular.js file.

Can I ignore these issues or should i replace attr with prop? Is there a version of angular I can upgrade to that will work for  jquery-2.2.4.js or jQuery-3.3.1.js? Maybe I should upgrade angular first and then jquery, not sure?

Files being linked:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try updating AngularJS version , you can try 1.7.5 .
This warning is about a change of behaviour in jQuery, not a removed function, 
so if you are getting only the JQMIGRATE Warning and everything works fine you can ignore it.